# Calling C++ dll from winforms application

Tags: c#, winforms, dll, dllimport

I undrstood the process of getting a c++ dll called in a c# console application. Can you please help me in getting the c++ dll called, in one of the button functions of a Form application that I have created in c# again.

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // call the c++ dll here.
        }
     }
}
```

I want the dll to be called in the function call "button3_Click".   I tried doing the

```
[DllImport("LicenseCheck.dll")];
public static extern void GetLicense();
```

call that stackoverflow taught me,  but then that worked only when I tried it on a console application.

Would certainly be happy if someone could help me. Thanks

Comment: What error / problem do you get when you try DllImport here?

Comment: Hi Baldrick,  when I try  doing this                                                                        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
             [DllImport("LicenseCheck.dll")]
             public static extern void GetLicense()                                                                           }    , it says " ; expected "  the other charaters have a red curly line beneath it. So would be happy if you could help me in, how do I call the dll here. Is that the correct way of calling it?? ( I'm sure it isn't the correct way )

Answer (score 1):

I think you're putting the DllImport statement inline with your code, instead of in the class body.

You need:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    [DllImport("LicenseCheck.dll")];
    public static extern void GetLicense();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // call the c++ dll here.
        GetLicense();
    }
 }
```

Please note that for this to work, the bitness of the DLL should match the bitness of your application, otherwise a BadImageFormatException exception will result.

Comment: Thanks Baldrick for letting me know, how to call the dll import at the right place. Unfortunaltely, I got this when I tried executing it....    An unhandled exception of type 'System.BadImageFormatException' occurred in WindowsFormsApplication1.exe    ......    Additional information: An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000B)....    I have placed the dll in the the location where the form.exe gets built.

Comment: Hi Baldrick, I got it... hip hip hurray...  Okay, so the problem was that my Dll was built in the 32 bit and I was trying to execute the 64bit form application.... That's when the above stated error happened.  Thank you stackoverflow and Baldrick for the knowledge. Praise God

Comment: HAHA was about to post just that very suggestion. I've updated my answer to include this point. Best of luck with the rest of your project.

Comment: @Baldrick or user2982029 I guess, you should better mention that the 32/64 version was the cause of the problem, as that might be hard to notice easily for some users who might experience the same trouble.

Comment: @Baldrick You mean "the bitness" you mentioned? :) Pretty "blurry" explanation for certain users, I guess.

Comment: @Agat: To be honest, the problem as described in the question is not related to bitness. It was related to the positioning of the DllImport statement. The bitness issue is separate, and is only part of this question because it happened to come up in the comments. So it's actually of doubtful relevance. Hence the very passing mention.

Comment: @Baldrick To be honest, the question related to `[DllImport(...)]` is pretty well-known problem, and if that was just a correct attribute in correct place using I would rather flag that as a duplicate. But due to the "complex" problem, including 32/64 architectures, I would still put more focus on that.